# Problem with SQLite3 on ipad. Keep getting 'constraint failed' error

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite

I have a common constraint problem. This is my table creation scheme :

> CREATE TABLE "Videos" ("CDate" TEXT NOT NULL , "Name" TEXT NOT NULL ,
>   "Path" TEXT NOT NULL )

And this is my code :

```
-(void)insertVideo:(VPVideo*)video
{
    NSString *foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Videos(CDate,Name,Path) VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%@')",[video.file creationDate],[video.file name],[video.file path]];
    const char *sql = [foo UTF8String];
    printf("%s",sql);
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    // Prepare the statement to compile the SQL query into byte-code
    int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if ( sqlResult!= SQLITE_OK) {
        NSAssert1(0,@"Error While creating add statement. '%d'",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
    {
        NSAssert1(0,@"Error while inserting data. '%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    else
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        //NSLog(@"id of the last insert is : '%lld'",sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database));

}
```

The debugger hits on "Error While inserting data" NSAssert1.
The full report is this:

> *** Assertion failure in -[DBAccess insertVideo:],
>   /Users/Vasilis/Desktop/Projects/IPhone/TestApp/TestApp/DBAccess.m:157
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while inserting
>   data. 'constraint failed''

I hope i gave you enough info about the problem so you are able to help me. I have already tried the following.

- Tried inserting the data through binding
- Checked for NULL values
- Changed the whole Database twice (i have no idea why, but i thought
  to try everything.)
- Tried the insert statement exactly as it is on
  firefox sqlite manager and seems to work fine

What do you believe is going wrong?
I forgot to mention that "select from" statement runs fine on ipad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! The problem was that the Iphone simulator was stuck and changes to the files where not saved, so i had to remove the compiled app from the simulator re-add all the files and compile the cleaned project again.